# Relation between conductor and discriminant of an elliptic curve

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, discriminant

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve with complex multiplication and let $F=\mathrm{End}(E)\otimes \mathbb{Q}$. Suppose $End(E) \cong \mathcal{O}$ where $\mathcal{O}$ is the order of conductor $f$ in $F$.

Is there any relationship between the minimal discriminant of $E$ and the field discriminant of $F/\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: How do you define $N_E$ ? The discriminant depends on the chosen equation or lattice for $E$. Did you mean $\Delta_E$ the minimal discriminant ? For elliptic curves with CM by an order $\mathbb{Z}+nO_F$ it is good to express the L-function of $E$ in term of some Hecke character $\psi$ on the ideals of $O_F$ coprimes to $(n)$, to see the primes of good and bad reductions. With $N $ the conductor of $\psi$ then the modular form of $\psi$ is a newform of level $N^2 \Delta_F$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. I saw another post on overflow a while back and I've been looking for a reference. I might be missing the hypothesis that the conductor and the discriminant are relatively prime.

Comment: A small note (from https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2022/definition-and-meaning-of-the-conductor-of-an-elliptic-curve/2026#2026) : "The conductor of the curve and the conductor of the order in the endomorphism ring are not equal in the CM case; it's just unfortunate terminology". Notice that the title of your question does not agree with the question itself.